# android 9 patch gradient

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm using the following 9 patch.

[image: Android 9 patch]

I was expecting android to create a gradient from orange to the yellowish right side, while it's working on android 4, on android 5 & 6 it creates a very precise change, as it is in my 9 patch.

Exemple:
[image]

The file is in the drawable-xxxhdpi (but i have similar 9 patches in other density relative folders), so dithering, gradient, and such graphic things should automatically apply.

Am i missing something or can't we use gradient in stretchable 9 patch anymore ? Thx

Comment: when running on android 4 switch the hardware acceleration off and see if you have the gradient (for example in the manifest: `<activity android:name=".SomeActivity" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...`)

Comment: Wow, you pointed something. 
Without hardware acceleration, i now have the same behavior on android 4, so it's definitely related. 
But with ICS, it's on by default, yet somehow my 9 patches are not accelerated. Thx for the hint, it helps me to search.

Comment: so the "gradient" is, as you can  see, a side effect,  don't relay on it and make the gradient by yourself

Comment: What do you mean by myself ? There is no way i can have a clean gradient with a provided resource. I will spend some more time to try to get the 9 patch as it used to be in 4.x. But still, i have a solution in case of lost hope !

Comment: something like [this](https://codeshare.io/JKupO), i gotta admit it is not the "easy" way but you have the freedom of drawing whatever you like

Answer (score 0):

You can check this workaround. (If anyone is still facing this issue)

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
```